# How can I simulate Alt F4 using Autokey or another method

Tags: keyboard, python, shortcut-keys, autokey

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

I just switched over to Linux and Autokey.

In Autokey, I would like use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to send the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> key stroke. I like to use this key stroke to automatically close or exit the most active window or program in the foreground.

I have tried using send keys but instead of actually sending the key stroke it just sends text.

If there is no way to simulate the keystroke, is there a way to send a close active window command?

Comment: what ubuntu version are you using (this could matter)

Comment: Currently it's Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Then you can simply make a shortcut with a combination of your choice without needing Autokey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install *xdotool* using `sudo apt install xdotool`, you can use it to simulate a lot of stuff.

Then, open *Settings > Devices > Keyboard* and click on the + sign at the bottom to add a new shortcut.

- Enter a name for your new shortcut such as *Alt Close*
- Enter `xdotool key Alt+F4` as the command
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> as your choice for running the command.

Comment: Can you please explain what "#/bin/bash" is, as I am still new to all this?

Comment: I've simplified the answer. The script route is useful for more complicated situations.

Comment: Yes this seems to have done it.

Comment: xdotools is amazing! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Looked around for a while on how to get this to work with Autokey.  Turns out you don't need it.  Thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of DK Bose, and especially as you are a newer user, I would prefer to point you to a simpler method that is exposed in the default user interface and does not rely on a third tool.

- Open "Settings", then locate "Devices" and "Keyboard" in the left bar. Alternatively, you may just type "keyboard", which will trigger a search and bring you to the Keyboard panel.
- Under the section "Windows", you can change the keyboard combination for "Close window". Click the entry. A "Set shortcut" dialog appears. Press your new keyboard combination to set it.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I'll give that a try.